# How come mass is conserved if the universe is formed from singularity?

Tags: cosmology, mass, universe, big-bang, singularities

If mass is conserved then how come there happened singularity?
since singularity is a point of infinite density and gravity.

Comment: Hi Xlee. Welcome to Phys.SE. By mass do you mean energy?

Comment: This video may help - [What really happened at the Big Bang?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZdvSJyHvUU)

Comment: Conservation of mass is a law in newtonian mechanics and does not hold for high energy and momentum particles. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass#Modern_physics

Answer (score 6):

In pop science you have this notion of infinite density. But the practice of correctly reasoned science is not quite like that and does not say that. Rather, what it says is that as we consider earlier times we find higher densities, until a very early time when the physical description is unknown so we don't know what the density was nor how it came about.

Answer (score 1):

Mass/energy is just the density multiplied by volume.

If the density becomes arbitrarily large then the mass/energy can be conserved if the volume becomes arbitrarily small. If you speculate that the universe really did have infinite density, then if it had at the same time zero volume, the product of density and volume could have been anything.